# Why is this move allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

A vector when it does a resize will attempt to use move semantics to move the objects from the old array to the new one. But if the templated object in the vector does not support a no throw `noexcept` move constructor then it will revert to using copy construction so that the `strong exception guarantee` is preserved.

But when I try this:

```
#include <vector>

class X
{
    public:
        // Needs default constructor
        X() {}

        // Copy operations disabled.
        X(X const&)             = delete;
        X& operator=(X const&)  = delete;

        X(X&&)              // throwable move constructor
        {}
        X& operator=(X&&)   // throwable move assignment.
        {return *this;}
};

int main()
{
    // Vector of Size zero
    std::vector<X>  data;

    // Vector of Size ten.
    // Since the move constructor can potentially throw
    // We have to copy elements when we do a resize
    //
    // But X has a disabled copy semantics
    // Thus I would expect a compile time error here.
    data.resize(10);
}
```

This compiles without error or warning:

```
> g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
> g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The strong exception safety guarantee is not provided for noncopyable elements that have a throwing move constructor.

[vector.capacity]/p12-14 (emphasis mine):

> ```
> void resize(size_type sz);
> ```
>
> 12 *Effects*: If `sz <= size()`, equivalent to calling `pop_back()`
>   `size() - sz` times. If `size() < sz`, appends `sz - size()`
>   default-inserted elements to the sequence.
>
> 13 *Requires*: `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable`
>   into `*this`.
>
> 14 *Remarks*: If an exception is thrown **other than by the move
>   constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`** there are no effects.

Note that this doesn't require `T` to be `CopyInsertable`.

Internally, the implementation likely uses `std::move_if_noexcept`, which, despite the name, is really "move if noexcept or if noncopyable".

Comment: As a user, I'd say this goes under principle of least surprise. I'd expect a noncopyable type with a move constructor to be movable in this manner regardless of exception safety guarantees.

Comment: If the move constructor throws, then isn't the vector in an undetermined state? Why would this be allowed?